# How do I skip play 5 strings without the A string without muting

Tags: guitar, technique

I bought the nirvana unplugged, and I saw the tablature say this,

```
E-------3-----
B-------0-----
G-------0----
D-------0---
A -----------
E ------3---
```

How would I play this?

Answer (score 3):

That tablature doesn't say anything about skipping strings.

An "O" on a strong means you play that open string without fretting it.

From what you have written it looks like you aren't playing the A string. If that's the case just mute it with the finger playing the 3rd fret on the low E.

To do this, just let it rest on the A string - many people do this by accident when learning, anyway.

Comment: I do this almost all the time; the low G and B together can get really harsh and muddy when distortion is involved; 3x0033 can be even better, since it's just roots and fifths.

Comment: @Dave - wouldn't have thought open chords would be used with distortion much, there's not a lot of control over them compared to barred chords.

Comment: Some work well, Tim. While my rhythm guitarist focuses on core fifths, I often use chords that would be considered much more jangly. It works well in certain conditions

Comment: Wouldn't have associated the term jangly with distorted chords!

Comment: As an example, have a listen to This Kiss by Metaltech. I'll pop a link up later but on small mobile right now. Rhythm uses 2 string power chords in the verse and chorus, but I'm mostly playing 5, 6 and 7 string chords - both barre and partial with some open strings. It helps round out the sound a little.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple open G chord, with the B note usually on the A string not played. One way is to touch the A string with the pad of the finger you press the bottom string down with,(most likely middle), so it's muted. It is a technique used a lot by guitarists, particularly when playing jazz chords, where a string in the middle, for instance, isn't needed. Another way is to pluck all 5 notes with thumb and 4 fingers - it's an acquired art, but worth working on, and particularly tricky when trying to hold a pick! Pick between index and thumb gives you 3 spare fingers, and who'd notice a missing string in the middle of the chord?